# shortest path in r (total cost and which steps) ideally with Igraph - simple mistake

Tags: r, igraph, shortest-path

I have a table that has in the first column the starting node, the ending node, and the cost to move in that direction.  It is one directional, you can't move backwards.   These are all the combinations.  Seems like I'm making an obvious mistake..

```
mygraph = structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), V2 = c(3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 
8L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), V3 = c(3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))

names(mygraph)=c('start','end','cost')

library(igraph)
mygraph = graph.data.frame(mygraph, directed=T) # I think this is right?
plot(mygraph) #looks completely wrong???
help=get.shortest.paths(mygraph,1,10)   #I'm doing something wrong want to see route and total cost of going from node 1-10
help
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the last term 'cost' in the following line to `weight`, it will generate the right solution.

```
names(mygraph) <- c('start', 'end', 'weight')
```

This happens because function `get.shortest.paths()` uses attribute `weight` (not `cost`) as the costs of edges.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is working as I expected.  I want to base the shortest path on the cost/weights.  This answer is giving me the shortest path from 1>10 as   1,3,6,10.   This has a cost of 3 for 1-3, 3 for 3-6, and then 3 for 6-10, for a total cost of 9.

on the other hand if I went
1-4
4-8
8-10

each of those paths have a cost of 2 for a total cost of 6 which is less.

Comment: It should be 'weight' instead of 'weights'. I am sorry about this.